# In PHP & MySQL Display date in day month Year Format from database

Tags: php, mysql, date, calendar

I've insert some dates in database & select these dates from the database using PHP & MySQL Code and display these dates in month wise format. Am using the following code:-

[image]

I Got the result like:-

```
2017-01-16 January
2017-01-26 January
2017-01-27 January
2017-02-02 February
2017-03-21 March
2017-03-22 March
```

---

I want to display month dates in that format:-

```
 January 
    2017-01-16
    2017-01-26
    2017-01-27
February
    2017-02-02 
March
    2017-03-21
    2017-03-22
```

Please help.

Comment: Please post your code as actual text content and not as image

Comment: I like your question, but since you have no text code I can't easily answer it, so I am giving up :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mo1 = "";
$qry = "SELECT DISTINCT ac_date FROM calender";
$exe = mysql_query($qry);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($exe)) {
     $ac_date = $row['ac_date'];
     $dateElements = explode('/', $ac_date);
     switch ($dateElements[0]){  

        case '01'    :  $mo = "January"; break;
        case '02'    :  $mo = "February"; break;
        case '03'    :  $mo = "March"; break;
        case '04'    :  $mo = "April"; break;
        case '05'    :  $mo = "May"; break;
        case '06'    :  $mo = "June"; break;
        case '07'    :  $mo = "July"; break;
        case '08'    :  $mo = "August"; break;
        case '09'    :  $mo = "September"; break;
        case '10'    :  $mo = "October"; break;  
        case '11'    :  $mo = "November"; break;
        case '12'    :  $mo = "December"; break;
     }
     if ($mo1 != $mo) {
          $activity.="<tr>
                      <td>$mo</td>
                      </tr>";
     }
     $activity.="<tr>
                 <td>$ac_date </td>
                 </tr>";
     $mo1=$mo;   
}
```